# Find index of column in matrix using lambda (python)

Tags: python, lambda

How can I find index of column with smallest sum of elements. I would like to find short solution which uses lambdas.
For example for given matrix:

```
[[7, 2, 7, 2, 8],
 [2, 9, 4, 1, 7],
 [3, 8, 6, 2, 4],
 [2, 5, 2, 9, 1],
 [6, 6, 5, 4, 5]]
```

It should return `3`. Because third column has smallest sum of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `numpy`, you can `sum` by columns and use the `argmin()` to find out the minimum sum index:

```
import numpy as np
np.array(lst).sum(axis = 0).argmin()
# 3
```

---

Or you can use list comprehension without using `numpy` package:

```
min(((i, sum(v)) for i, v in enumerate(zip(*lst))), key = lambda x: x[1])[0]
# 3
```

- use `zip(*lst)` to transpose the list
- enumerate to loop through columns (since it has been transposed)
- for each column take the index, and sum of the column
- calculate the minimum pair by the sum, which returns a tuple (index, minimum)

Comment: Based on your sollution I've found even shorter sollution which uses straight Python: 
          `min(enumerate(map(sum,zip(*m))),key=lambda x:x[1])[0]`

Comment: Not necessarily faster though since both approaches use only generators  but surely a nicer and shorter one.